# Can I link merchant items in chat?

Tags: diablo-iii

I tried to shift-click an item a merchant was selling in chat to a friend, however it doesn't work.

Is there something special I need to do to link a merchant's item in chat, or is that not possible unless I buy the item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot link items from the merchant windows. The shift-click linking only works for items that you actually posses.